# Locking folders from accessing in windows

Tags: windows, directory, operating-system, dom-events, folder-access

I want to write a python script that can run at the background and monitor the folders accessed. If a particular folder is accessed, it should ask for password. If the password is correct, the folder can be accessed or else not.
But I do not know how to monitor for if a particular file is opened.If a log is generated for it, or if we can capture such a event.

I was going through the internet and I found something called "folder access event". But there is not much about it, or about how to access it.

Comment: Just a thought: If you want to protect a folder with a password, block unpermitted access to it and to make sure the permissions really work - don't code something the way you describe. All one needs is to kill the task of your python script and the access wouldn't be monitored anymore. Data access and security should be done right, if wanted. My tip would be to use proven secure methods, like creating veracrypt containers, for example. Depending on your situation, maybe even using correct user and rights management with folder permissions will help.